# How can higher-dimensional projection maps be described mathematically?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry

**New question**: (resulting from discussions with Sabyasachi)

I am wonder how higher-dimensional projection maps, analogous to for example the Mercator, Miller, Behrmann projections, can be described mathematically. How do the resulting distortions and/or discontinuities compare to the distortions/discontinuities in the projections we know from the 'traditional' projection maps used to project the curved earth's surface on a flat piece of paper?

**Original question**:

So there exist quite a few map [projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections) that project our 3-dimensional earth on a 2-dimensional surface.

Imagine, however, that our earth would be a 4-dimensional entity. I was wondering whether there exist natural generalisations of these maps that would project our (imaginary) 4-dimensional earth on a 3-dimensional "surface". We could generalise even further and wonder whether there exist projections form a k-dimensional earth on a (k-1)-dimensional "surface".

Comment: This is just a projection map, i.e., a mapping such that $\mathbf{P=P^2}$.

Comment: The problem here is that although our earth itself is $3$-dimensional, the land/water surface is 2D and that is the only thing that is mapped. We don't map the layers or rock, or the core. Whatever this 4D earth is, we would be able to map any 3 dimensions, not all 4. The same applies for your k-d world.

Comment: @Sabyasachi ah ok, thank you. Does this render my question useless?

Comment: @MaxMuller depends on an individual's definition of "useless". To me it certainly is a meaningful question. For one thing, although the surface is 2D is exists in 3D space, and therefore is a curved 2D surface, curving in the third dimension. This means when we map it to a non curved flat sheet of paper, there are either distortions, or discontinuities. I would certainly be interested to know what a discontinuity/distortion would mean in 3D space. We have seen effects of that certainly. For instance our universe is actually 4D.well 11D but 4 dimensions will suffice for now..continued comment

Comment: ... so because there are 4 dimensions, but we only sense a 3D "projection" there are distortions we see. If i oversimplify, one aspect of relativity states that the earth's(or any other object) orbit is actually a straight line, in curved space. Like if you drew a straight line along the surface from new york to london, it would actually be a circle centered at the earth's center, but mapping it to a mercator projection would make it look like a curved line, which would make it look like a plane flying from ny to london is taking a longer route, but it is in reality the shortest....

Comment: ....same applies for any object that has a curved trajectory in a gravitational field. Because space is bent, it is actually taking the shortest path. (This was an oversimplified gist of relativity as applied to gravity, this actually makes better predictions than newtonian gravity $F = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$)

Comment: @Sabyasachi ok, thank you! I guess a better phrasing of this question would be: how can higher-dimensional projection maps, analogous to for example the Mercator, Miller, Behrmann  projections, be described mathematically? How do the resulting distortions and/or discontinuities compare to the distortions/discontinuities in the projections we know?

Comment: @MaxMuller yes that'd be a good question, one I am certainly willing to see answered by someone.

Comment: The modern (for the last 100 or so years) language for discussing these issues is via a "smooth atlas" or "atlas of charts," which will be covered in pretty much any introductory book on differential topology or differential geometry. You can start by reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology)) Wikipedia article. As for a comparison to the "classical" projections, it all depends on the choice of particular atlas/charts and is way too broad to be answerable.